# does PDF support data degradation protection?

Tags: pdf, integrity

So we can add signatures to PDF files, which sign the content hash of the document.
however, if one bit flips due to bitrot, the file will be corrupt and the signature worthless.
Does PDF have some built in data integrity protection that would allow it to repair bitrot to a certain degree?

I'm aware that this can be achieved on a filesystem level, but I wonder if the PDF format itself also has facilities for this, and if so, how they can be enabled and whether they are included in PDF/A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does PDF have some built in data integrity protection that would allow it to repair bitrot to a certain degree?

No. Quite the contrary, data streams in PDFs may be (and often are) compressed using FLATE. In uncompressed content streams a bit flip usually only damages a single instruction or two, often having only an effect on small parts of the page rendering. But in a compressed content stream it usually damages all instructions starting at the flip. If this happens early in the stream, the whole page cannot be rendered anymore.

Comment: but technically it should nevetheless be possible to apply error correction after compression - of course that adds a bit of data overhead, but often much less than the compression reduced the original data

Comment: Of course you *can* devise compression-plus-error-correction; as far as I know, though, FLATE *does not* offer error correction. Neither does LZW or RLE. And those are the three generic compression filters specified for PDF. Error correction has not been a topic in PDF design.

Comment: Thanks, that's a pity given how PDF is used for digital long terrm storage, that'd be a neat feature.

Comment: Probably. But you could also see this as *Separation of Concerns* in action.

Comment: sure, but you could also separate the signing of documents out o pdf. It is neat to have signatures embedded right into the document. Would be neat if these signatures were also protected against bitrot right inside the document

Comment: There is a difference: If you have to process PDFs from the wild but are not interested in signatures, you can trivially ignore them. If PDF was stored with a sensible error correction code applied and you had to process PDFs from the wild but were not interested in error correction, you'd still have to decode through the error correction layer (probably some Hamming code like encoding of the PDF data). Thus, error correction would make generic PDF processing more difficult, signatures don't.